# How to do thread safe shared_ptr modification and access?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, boost-asio

Goal: I want to modify internal information and access this information from many threads synchronously as fast as possible

I simplified code bellow, but this is how I tried to achieve this.

I have 2 shared pointers.

One is called `m_mutable_data` and the other is called `m_const_data`.

`m_mutable_data` is updated in strand guarded way. `m_const_data` is updated with contents of m_mutable_data every 60s also in the strand guarded way.

This is the only place `m_const_data` shared pointer is reset with new data. `m_const_data` is read synchronously by many threads, 1000+ times per second.

**Code**

```
class black_list_container : public std::enable_shared_from_this<black_list_container>
{

struct meta_data
{
    bool blacked;
}

struct black_list_data
{
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t,meta_data> data;
}

public:

#pragma optimize( "", off )
bool is_blacked(uint32_t id) 
{
    // This call is called from many different threads (1000+ calls per second)
    // should be synchronous and as fast as possible

    auto c = m_const_data;

    return c->data[id].blacked;
}
#pragma optimize( "", on )

#pragma optimize( "", off )
void update_const_data() 
{
    // Called internaly by timer every 60s to update m_const_data with contents of m_mutable_data
    // Guarded with strand

    m_strand->post([self{shared_from_this()}]{

        auto snapshot = new black_list_data();
        snapshot->data = m_mutable_data->data;
        m_const_data.reset(snapshot);

    });
}
#pragma optimize( "", on )


private:

void internal_modification_mutable_data()
{
    // Called internaly by different metrics
    // Guarded with strand

    m_strand->post([self{shared_from_this()}]{

        // .... do some modification on internal m_mutable_data

    });
}

boost::asio::io_context::strand m_strand;
std::shared_ptr<black_list_data> m_mutable_data;
std::shared_ptr<black_list_data> m_const_data;

};
```

Very, very seldom this code crashes in method 'is_blacked' on line

```
auto c = m_const_data;
```

This is the backtrace

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./STRATUM-01'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fe09aaf1387 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fe09aaf1387 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fe09aaf2a78 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fe09ab33ed7 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fe09ab3c299 in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00000000005fae36 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0x7fe0440aeaa0) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:154
#5  0x00000000006b9205 in ~__shared_count (this=<synthetic pointer>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:684
#6  ~__shared_ptr (this=<synthetic pointer>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1123
#7  ~shared_ptr (this=<synthetic pointer>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:93
#8  black_list_container_impl::is_blacked (this=0x7fe08c287e50, id=23654) at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/validator/src/black_list_container.cpp:69
```

I'm not exactly sure why destruction of shared_ptr is called in frame #7

Obviously I did not achieve my goal so please direct me into pattern that actually achieves my goal in thread safe way.

I know I could have used

```
std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<black_list_data>> m_const_data;
```

but would not this affect performance while reading from many different threads?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to my question in this article [Atomic Smart Pointers](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/atomic-smart-pointers).

So I have to change code in `update_const_data()` to

```
    auto snapshot = std::make_shared<black_list_data>();
    snapshot->data = m_mutable_data->data;
    std::atomic_store(&m_const_data, snapshot);
```

and code in `is_blacked()` to

```
auto c = std::atomic_load(&m_const_data);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it is implementation defined whether the implementation is lock-free (you can use [`atomic<shared_ptr<T>>::is_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) to detect it)

Comment: @sehe Thank you for the warning. I read about that on https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/the-atomic-flag which states "So these atomics have a method is_lock_free to check if the atomic uses internally a mutex. On the popular platforms, I always get the answer false. But you should be aware of that."